# Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content:

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having some problems with create with JSON.Net. When I try to parse it, it gives me following error:

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content:

I tried validating it with http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,".

My JSON is as below:

```
{"StaffID":"S01","StaffRank":"Manager"},{"StaffID":"S02","StaffRank":"Waiter"}
```

How to deserialize it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to surround that with square brackets, which denotes that it's an array:

```
    [{"StaffID":"S01","StaffRank":"Manager"},{"StaffID":"S02","StaffRank":"Waiter"}]
```

Comment: After I tried I get the new error which is:"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'tbl_Staff' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.{"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array."

Comment: How about just helping him rather than typing all in caps. Sometimes people don't know how to read JSON when they are starting.

Comment: I get the same error as @HowardHee comment, so I had to deserialize my code as a "list" of object: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Invoice.Root>>(result);`. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

As of [Release 11.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1), Json.NET now natively supports parsing comma-delimited JSON in the same way it supports parsing [newline delimited JSON](http://specs.okfnlabs.org/ndjson/):

> New feature - Added support for reading multiple comma delimited values with [`JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm).

Thus the answer to [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729419/3744182) by [Yuval Itzchakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870803/yuval-itzchakov) should work here also.  Define an extension method:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FromDelimitedJson<T>(TextReader reader, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { CloseInput = false, SupportMultipleContent = true })
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);

            while (jsonReader.Read())
            {
                if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
                    continue;
                yield return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, given a data model created to hold an individual item in the comma-separated list such as:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string StaffID { get; set; }
    public string StaffRank { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize the JSON string shown like so:

```
var jsonString = @"{""StaffID"":""S01"",""StaffRank"":""Manager""},{""StaffID"":""S02"",""StaffRank"":""Waiter""}";

var list = JsonExtensions.FromDelimitedJson<RootObject>(new StringReader(jsonString)).ToList();
```

This approach may be preferable when deserializing a very large sequence of comma-delimited objects from a large file, because it is not necessary to load the entire file into a `string` then add `'['` and `']'` to the beginning and end.  In [*Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage) Newtonsoft recommends deserializing large files directly from a stream, so instead a `StreamReader` can be passed into `JsonExtensions.FromDelimitedJson()` which will then stream through the file deserializing each object separately.