# Serialize as NDJSON using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, ndjson

Is it possible to serialize to [NDJSON](http://ndjson.org) (Newline Delimited JSON) using Json.NET? The Elasticsearch API uses NDJSON for bulk operations, and I can find nothing suggesting that this format is supported by *any* .NET libraries.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729063/line-delimited-json-serializing-and-de-serializing) provides guidance for deserializing NDJSON, and it was noted that one could serialize each row independently and join with newline, but I would not necessarily call that *supported*.

Comment: That link points to a domain grab. It was created only a couple of years ago, while providers like AWS and Azure use newline-delimeted JSON for several years

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Json.NET does not currently have a built-in method to serialize a collection to NDJSON, the simplest answer would be to write to a single `TextWriter` using a separate [`JsonTextWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) for each line, setting [`CloseOutput = false`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_CloseOutput.htm) for each:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void ToNewlineDelimitedJson<T>(Stream stream, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        // Let caller dispose the underlying stream 
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false, true), 1024, true))
        {
            ToNewlineDelimitedJson(textWriter, items);
        }
    }

    public static void ToNewlineDelimitedJson<T>(TextWriter textWriter, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            // Formatting.None is the default; I set it here for clarity.
            using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.None, CloseOutput = false })
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
            }
            // https://web.archive.org/web/20180513150745/http://specs.okfnlabs.org/ndjson/
            // Each JSON text MUST conform to the [RFC7159] standard and MUST be written to the stream followed by the newline character \n (0x0A). 
            // The newline charater MAY be preceeded by a carriage return \r (0x0D). The JSON texts MUST NOT contain newlines or carriage returns.
            textWriter.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jozq9H).

Since the individual NDJSON lines are likely to be short but the number of lines might be large, this answer suggests a streaming solution to avoid the necessity of allocating a single string larger than 85kb.  As explained in [*Newtonsoft Json.NET Performance Tips*](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage), such large strings end up on the [large object heap](https://web.archive.org/web/20150322075339/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx) and may subsequently degrade application performance.

Comment: Accepting as answer due to the use of a JsonTextWriter. It seems like this is the most sane approach in the context of what the library already provides, and it notably more performant than the other answer's approach of creating a new TextWriter for each line.

Comment: Actually, the above is the answer that creates a JsonTextWriter for each line.

Comment: @jlavallet - `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` internally creates both a `StringWriter` and a `JsonTextWriter`; see [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L647) for details.  Since the individual JSON lines are likely to be short but the number of lines might be large, I suggested a streaming solution to avoid allocating a single string larger than 85kb as recommended [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage).

Comment: Small clarification: the original answer is disposing each `JsonTextWriter` to force the JsonTextWriter to call `Flush()`. This is what @dbc was explaining in his comment reply about large strings. As an alternative to recreating the JsonTextWriter every time, you can move its `using` block outside of the `foreach` and explicitly call `Flush()` at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
string ndJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented);
```

but now I see that you are not just wanting the serialized object to be pretty printed. If the object you are serializing is some kind of collection or enumeration, could you not just do this yourself by serializing each element?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var element in collection)
{
    sb.AppendLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element, Formatting.None));
}

// use the NDJSON output
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: It certainly would be valid to serialize one line at a time and append, but as I pointed out: this is not functionality I can get from Json.NET out-of-the-box. 

It's a fair question whether or not Json.NET _should_ support this format explicitly. What would be the input type for NDJson, an array of objects?

Comment: I agree that it's a fair question whether Json.NET can support this out-of-the-box.

Comment: As to what the input type would be – I suppose from what I quickly read about the NDJSON format, that would depend on the context. It would be "a line of data" that should be separately handled from other "lines of data". What is your context? The line of data could be a simple object with a few properties, a complex object with multiple levels of sub objects, or just a string, You would have to tell me what should appear on each line.

Comment: @jlvallet NDJSON allows for _any_ valid JSON to be transmitted in this format. If you wanted to produce this output with a set of mixed objects in .NET, some type boxing/unboxing would be necessary. Anyway, it was meant more as a rhetorical prompt. Maybe the best implementation is simply to build a custom JsonTextWriter for this type of serialziation, eschewing any direct support in the library.