# Adding objects to json collection

Tags: c#, json, file, json.net, deserialization

I geting data from API in JSON and storing it localy in file using JSON.NET but there is up to 2,5 million records. It works like this :

- get small amount of data from API and add it to List object
- save in new file (if file not exists) or OVERRIDE it (if file exists)

My problem is that List of objects must store large amount od data (millions)

My save looks like this

```
public bool SaveJSON(string path, TData data,Formatting formatting = Formatting.Indented)
{
        bool success = false;
        while(!success)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    serializer.Serialize(file, data);
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : " ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return true;

}
```

With this JSON file looks like

```
[
   {
     ...
   },
   ...
   {
     ...
   }
]
```

I know there is File method [File.AppendText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) but with it i get file like this

```
[
   {
     ...
   },
   ...
   {
     ...
   }
]
[
   {
     ...
   }
]
```

so non-separated arrays and it can't be deserialized correctly.

How can I deal with this? I thought about removing last line

> ]

but all solutions I found were about reading whole file to the string and then making changes in it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to append/merge some newly received objects to some others already saved to disk file?

Comment: Why are you trying to append anything to JSON?  Deserialize the JSON, modify the object, and Reserialize it.  Trying to manually change the json (string/file) is an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: Before deserializing, do a `string.Replace("][", "")`. Or write brackets and comma manualy and serialize item by item instead of whole array. To add new item, replace the last `]` by a `,`

Comment: Exactly, but I must store in memory whole collection and then save it as new file every time. But I want just append some objects to existing file.

Comment: And it is good to deserialize the few millions objects..?

Comment: Rather than "pure" JSON, you might consider switching to [Newline Delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/) -- basically, a bunch of separate JSON objects concatenated together.  See [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063) and [Serialize as NDJSON using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44787652) for how to read and write this format with Json.NET.