# Convert Json to Newline Delimit json

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to convert my json to Newline delimiter to insert data in BigQuery from C#(.NET Application).
Please suggest the workaround

Input

```
[  
   {  
      "DashboardCategoryId":1,
      "BookingWindows":[  
         {  
            "DaysRange":"31-60 Days",
            "BookingNumber":2
         },
         {  
            "DaysRange":"Greater Than 1 year",
            "BookingNumber":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "DashboardCategoryId":1,

      "BookingWindows":[  
         {  
            "DaysRange":"61-120 Days",
            "BookingNumber":1
         },
         {  
            "DaysRange":"8-14",
            "BookingNumber":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Required Output

```
{"DashboardCategoryId": 1,"BookingWindows": [{"DaysRange": "31-60 Days","BookingNumber":2},{"DaysRange": "Greater Than 1 year","BookingNumber": 1}]}
 {"DashboardCategoryId": 1,"BookingWindows": [{"DaysRange": "61-120 Days","BookingNumber":1},{"DaysRange": "8-14","BookingNumber": 1}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c)

Comment: To serialize an enumerable as newline-delimited JSON, see [Serialize as NDJSON using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44787652/3744182).  Does that answer your question, or do you need to know how to apply that answer?

Comment: This code is not generating newline delimit json.

Comment: @Mayank - *This code is not generating newline delimit json.* - to whom were you replying?  Can you provide a [mcve] if your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already loaded your JSON array into memory as, say, a `List<JToken>`, you can write it to newline delimited JSON by using the answer from *[Serialize as NDJSON using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44787652/3744182)*.

However, since BigQuery newline delimited JSON files do tend to be... big, I'm going to suggest instead an entirely streaming solution:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void ToNewlineDelimitedJson(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

        // Let caller dispose the underlying streams.
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(readStream, encoding, true, 1024, true))
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(writeStream, encoding, 1024, true))
        {
            ToNewlineDelimitedJson(textReader, textWriter);
        }
    }

    public static void ToNewlineDelimitedJson(TextReader textReader, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader) { CloseInput = false, DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None })
        {
            ToNewlineDelimitedJson(jsonReader, textWriter);
        }
    }

    enum State { BeforeArray, InArray, AfterArray };

    public static void ToNewlineDelimitedJson(JsonReader jsonReader, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        var state = State.BeforeArray;
        do
        {
            if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment || jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.None || jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.Undefined || jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
            else if (state == State.BeforeArray && jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                state = State.InArray;
            }
            else if (state == State.InArray && jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                state = State.AfterArray;
            }
            else
            {
                // Formatting.None is the default; I set it here for clarity.
                using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.None, CloseOutput = false })
                {
                    jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader);
                }
                // http://specs.okfnlabs.org/ndjson/
                // Each JSON text MUST conform to the [RFC7159] standard and MUST be written to the stream followed by the newline character \n (0x0A). 
                // The newline charater MAY be preceeded by a carriage return \r (0x0D). The JSON texts MUST NOT contain newlines or carriage returns.
                textWriter.Write("\n");

                // Root value wasn't an array after all, so end writing with one item.
                if (state == State.BeforeArray)
                    state = State.AfterArray;
            }
        }
        while (jsonReader.Read() && state != State.AfterArray);
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
using (var readStream = File.OpenRead(fromFileName))
using (var writeStream = File.Open(toFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    JsonExtensions.ToNewlineDelimitedJson(readStream, writeStream);
}
```

This takes advantage of the method [`JsonWriter.WriteToken(JsonReader)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteToken.htm) to write and format directly from a `JsonReader` to a `JsonWriter` without ever loading the entire JSON token hierarchy into memory.

Working sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sLLa7N).

Answer (score 0):

[Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) can be used to format JSON.
I've found example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407175/2557730):

```
private static string FormatJson(string json)
{
    dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
}
```