# How to Append text to Dictionary using Json Writer

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, key-value

Using Newston.Json to Store Balances to Bank Account. When I add new entry, it replaces the old one, I want to append key value pairs to existing notepad file, instead it replaces the old balances.

> Key = Bank Name with Account
>
> Value = Balance

**Global Variable**

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, float>> vals3 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();
```

// Now Add Balance to Accounts

```
BankWithAccount = BankList.Text + AccountNotextBox1.Text;
balance = float.Parse(BalanceTxtBox.Text);

vals3.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>(BankWithAccount, balance));
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Balances.txt")))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vals3);
            sw.Write(json);
        }
```

Comment: Are you appending key values or json?

Comment: A [well-formed JSON file](https://www.json.org/) has a single root value (object, array or primitive), so you cannot **append** a key/value pair to it.  You must parse it and insert it.  If you need to write frequently and read occasionally (e.g. as in writing a log file), as an alternative to JSON you might consider newline-delimited JSON, see [Serialize as NDJSON using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44787652/3744182) and [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for File.CreateText(String):

> Creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text. If the file already exists, its contents are overwritten.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=net-5.0

What you probably want is File.AppendText(String):

> Creates a StreamWriter that appends UTF-8 encoded text to an existing file, or to a new file if the specified file does not exist.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-5.0

Comment: When I write File.AppendText, I am getting following error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: [. Path '', line 1, position 53.'

Comment: I have found is this issue, when a same window is open, everything works fine but when i close window and reopen, then it replaces the text file, otherwise File.CreateText is appending text.

Comment: So... are you creating 1 big JSON object or is each line an individual JSON object?