# I am having an error with deserializing a json array into a custom array class with newtonsoft.json, and do not know how to fix it c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to load a saved array class called "Grid" which is an array of a class called "location" using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
and am getting an error
Here is the error

```
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'town_build_1_controller_individual_blocks+Grid' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array
```

But even though I have scoured the newtonsoft documentation I don't know how to fix it

this is the code that is causing the error

```
using (StreamReader fileR = new StreamReader(("savedata/buildingtown1/" + filename)))
{
    string gridinfo2 = fileR.ReadLine();
    Grid endgridinfo = new Grid();
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Grid>(gridinfo2);
    print(gridinfo2);
    visualhandler(endgridinfo);
    print("read info" + endgridinfo.grid[0, 0].Type);
    fileR.Close();
}
```

The line is

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Grid>(gridinfo2);
```

This is my definition for Grid:

```
public class Grid
{
    //public Location [,] grid = new Location [3, 3];
    public Location [,] grid = { { new Location(), new Location(), new Location() }, { new Location(), new Location(), new Location() }, { new Location(), new Location(), new Location() } };
}
```

this is my definition for Location:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

the file that I am trying to load contains this

```
[{"Type":1,"Level":0},{"Type":0,"Level":0},{"Type":0,"Level":0}],
[{"Type":0,"Level":0},{"Type":0,"Level":0},{"Type":0,"Level":0}],
[{"Type":0,"Level":0},{"Type":0,"Level":0},{"Type":0,"Level":0}]
```

thanks for your help, and I know im quite bad at coding so please don't just comment that
Many thanks,
law_man123

Comment: Deserialize into a `List<List<Location>>` and build your grid from there.

Comment: How would I do that, could You give me an example snippet. Sorry this is my first time doing something as complicated as this

Comment: I just tried it but List is not recognised, what should I do

Comment: Import the proper namespace, namely `System.Collections.Generic`. Then call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Location>>()`.

Comment: but how would I turn it back into a grid

Comment: Does your file contain an extra `[` at the beginning and an extra `]` at the end?  If not, it looks to be [newline-delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/) rather than a single JSON container.  To read newline-delimited JSON see [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063).

Answer (score 0):

You're not deserializing a grid object your deserialzing a Location[,].

```
var result =   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location[,]>(gridinfo2);
Grid endgridinfo = new Grid(){ grid = result };
```

This is what it would have to look like for your code to work as is. When trying to deserialize something that complicated I would try to serialize what you're expecting it to go into and check for difference.

```
{
    "grid": [
      [
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        },
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        },
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        },
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        },
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        },
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        },
        {
          "Type": 0,
          "Level": 0
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```