# How to deserialize Json String dynamically

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization

I have consume Survey data via `SSE Stream` that gives me each persons answers line by line with this format for `Survey X`:

```
{"data":["4482359","12526","5","5","","Yes, that is right","1"]}
```

I read it into a `List(of String)` using `Streamreader`

```
 Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
 Dim myList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

 While sr.Peek >= 0
     myList.Add(sr.ReadLine())
 End While
```

Now I want to deserialize the strings so I get the entries into properties of a class (let us call it `tmpUserData`) that I can access. I have tried this using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
Dim tmpUserData As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(myList(i))
```

but looking into `tmpUserData` the deserialization does not split the entries as

```
(1) User1
  (1) "4482359"
  (2) "12526"
  (3) "5"
  (4) ""
...    
(2) User1
  (1) "5847895"
  (2) "33568"
  (3) "6"
  (4) "2"
...
```

but instead it just put everything into one entry

```
(1) "4482359","12526","5","5","","Yes, that is right","1"
```

The reason why I cannot just write a class and put the data into it like

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myclass)(myList(i))
```

is that this has to be dynamically since the number and structure of strings differs for different surveys. So `Survey Y` might looks like:

```
{"data":["Peter","Jackson","Albert Street","5","","1"]}
```

Could anyone help me get what I am looking for so the entries of each Survery Particpant are properly deserialized? `C#` Solution is welcome as well.

Comment: you can deserialize given json to `class MyClass { public List<string> data {get;set;}}`

Comment: That looks like line-delimited JSON.  You can deserialize it as shown in [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063) and/or [What is the correct way to use JSON.NET to parse stream of JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53867959).  If you need a vb.net port there's one... here https://dotnetfiddle.net/1jOyka (linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867959/wrong-json-format-cannot-deserialize-json-into-listof-string#comment94631004_53867959)).

Comment: You are asking about dynamic deserialization, how does non-dynamic deserialization look like?

Comment: dynamic? your all examples looks like json object with json array property named data  ... there is nothing dynamic here (other than array length)

Comment: You write you need a solution in `C#` those keywords look like Visual Basic to me.

Comment: You need to provide JSON with at least two entries so we can know in what way is it structured. eg: {"data":["4482359","12526","5","5","","Yes, that is right","1"],["4482359","12526","5","5","","Yes, that is right","1"]...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is the content of the stream:

```
{"data":["4482359","12526","5","5","","Yes, that is right","1"]}
{"data":["2223446","65432","3","3","","Nope, that's not right","0"]}
(...)
```

you can deserialize these lines using a `List<class>`. Something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> data { get; set; }
}
```

That JSON streaming can be deserialize in two simple ways:

- If you don't really need to parse the stream line by line, read the stream to end, then use a [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) to read the resulting string and [JsonSerializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) to deserialize the reader's result into an instance of the class you're using as container for the data:

```
List<RootObject> dataObjects = new List<RootObject>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var JSONObject = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(JSONObject)) { SupportMultipleContent = true };
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    while (reader.Read()) {
        dataObjects.Add(serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(reader));
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

VB.Net version:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property MyData As List(Of String)
End Class
```

```vb
Dim dataObjects As New List(Of RootObject)()
Using sr As New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim JSONObject As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

    Dim reader = New JsonTextReader(New StringReader(JSONObject)) With {
        .SupportMultipleContent = True
    }
    Dim serializer = New JsonSerializer()
    While reader.Read()
        dataObjects.Add(serializer.Deserialize(Of RootObject)(reader))
    End While
    reader.Close()
End Using
```

- If you need to parse the stream line by line for some reason not specified here, you could insert an array delimiter `[` before the first line and `]` after the last line, separating each line with a (comma). You have now a functional array that can be deserialized with [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(JSON)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm)

The *final product* will look like this:

```
[ {"data":["value1","value2","value3", (...)]},
  {"data":["value1","value2","value3", (...)]} ]
```

```
List<RootObject> dataObjects = new List<RootObject>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var JSONObject = sr.ReadToEnd();
    dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(JSONObject);
}
```

VB.Net version:

```vb
Dim dataObjects As New List(Of RootObject)()

Using sr As New StreamReader(stream)
    Dim JSONObject As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
    dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of RootObject))(JSONObject)
End Using
```

Comment: the solution (first one) works perfect. thanks a lot!

Comment: Allright. Do you need a `VB.Net` *translation* of these methods?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I was able to translate it.

Comment: OK. I'll post it here anyway, because the question is also tagged `VB.Net`.

Answer (score -1):

why are you using StreamReader for reading JSON data?

you can use JObject to parse your json and get data out of it.

```
var json = @"{""data"":[""4482359"",""12526"",""5"",""5"","""",""Yes, that is right"",""1""]}";
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

List<string> lst = (obj["data"]).ToObject<List<string>>();

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
```

Comment: For JObject.Parse an external library is needed (Newtonsoft).

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` as well? Dont you know that they are in the same library?

Comment: Fair, I mistook it for JavaScriptSerializer.