# How to parse JSON with Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json, csv

I created an ASP.NET Application, where I have to parse a csv file with a json structure.
The csv file itself is structured like:

```
{"Instance":"abc","Date":"2019-06-03T00:00:02.056Z","Identification":"someFunction","Type":"DurationInMs","Value":"5","iserror":"False""}
```

I get the jsonCsvData as a string and tried to parse it. Then I want to save some of the elements of this json object into a db.

```
        public IActionResult ReadJsonCsvData(string jsonCsvData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReadJsonCsvData");

            ChartData chartData = new ChartData();

            var lines = jsonCsvData.Split("\n");

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var values = JObject.Parse(line);

                var first = string.Concat(values["Instance"]); //Output for first: ""
            }
        }
```

The problem now is, that the variable `first` is an empty string. The result should be (like in the json structure example above) "abc".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just do something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonCsvData)` to get you going, then you can start creating concrete classes that match your  schema.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius: There's no need to do that. This code should work.

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV, that looks like line-delimited JSON.  To parse such a file see [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729419).

Comment: You should put a debug point and check what are  values in your jsonCsvData and values variable

Comment: The end of your JSON doesn't look valid to me... I strongly suspect you're not parsing the exact data you think you are. I suggest you dump the value of `line` to the console on each iteration.

Comment: There is an extra quote at the end of the JSON, which makes it invalid. Other than that, doing `first.Value<string>()` should give you `"abc"`.

Comment: You can take advantage of VS's Paste Special Feature to create a class from Json or XML. Then It would be very easy to deserialize using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourclass>(jsonCsvData).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help but here is my solution (remove one of " at the end of your Json).

I use the "Jobject" to parse Json as I want. Import this two reference.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft;
```

Then you have to create your JObject :

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
```

Then to retrieve specifics data, you just have to search in your object just like you do with a dictionary with key :

```
instanceFromJson = o["Instance"].ToString;
dateFromJson = o["Date"].ToString;
```

If you have a table in your "instance" json object you can retrieve all data from this list just like that :

```
foreach (var item in o["Instance"]["tabFromInstanceObject"])
{
    MyList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I have already found a way to solve this problem, thank you either!