# JSON logging in NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

1. How do I set up **NLog** so that structured text is saved to the **json** file?

Project: https://github.com/jhon65496/LoggingWriteJsonWinFrmQ1/tree/Logging

The ultimate goal:

1. Get the fields from the NLog:

- DateTime;
- ProjectName where logging is triggered;
- ClassName where logging is triggered;
- Methodname where logging is triggered;
- LineNumber where the logging is triggered;
- Duration of execution between steps.

2. Save to JSON
3. Analyze JSON in Excel.

I'm using this code now.

**NLog.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="log.json">
            <!-- Добавляем layout для вывода необходимых параметров -->
            <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
                <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                <attribute name="message" layout="${message}"/>
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Logger1**

```cs
internal class Logger1
{

    public void CreateLogger()
    {
        Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                    
        log.Info("info message. Step-1");
        log.Info("info message. Step-2");
    }
}
```

**Form1**

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateLogger();
    }

    public void CreateLogger()
    {
        Logger1 lg = new Logger1();
        lg.CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

Now I get the following contents in the **log.json** file:

```json
{ "time": "2024-02-28 12:54:23.1273", "message": "info message. Step-1" }
{ "time": "2024-02-28 12:54:23.2433", "message": "info message. Step-2" }
```

I expect the following content in the "log.json" file:

```json
[
    { 
        "time": "2024-02-28 12:54:23.1273", 
        "message": "info message. Step-1" },
    { 
        "time": "2024-02-28 12:54:23.2433", 
        "message": "info message. Step-2" }
]
```

---

## Update-1

Added `indentJson="true"`

`<layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" indentJson="true">`

**NLog.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="log.json">
            <!-- Добавляем layout для вывода необходимых параметров -->
            <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" indentJson="true">
                <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                <attribute name="message" layout="${message}"/>
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>
 
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

The result

```
{
  "time": "2024-02-28 15:46:11.0583",
  "message": "info message. Step-1"
}
{
  "time": "2024-02-28 15:46:11.1183",
  "message": "info message. Step-2"
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with NLog but what you are seeing is not surprising -- if there were a closing bracket, it would need to be written after the last item is logged (which NLog cannot know) or it would need to be overritten in the log file for every newly logged item.

Comment: I haven't used NLog but I suspect that's not how it works, see [this example](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout). It's most likely just appending a structured record to a file and NOT reading the file and then appending to the array of JSON objects inside of it. To read it as an array of objects would likely be the responsibility of the tool being used to analyze the log records.

Comment: NLog only supports newline-delimited-JSON (NDJSON). So I suggest your find a file-viewer that supports NDJSON, or create file-transformer that changes it into wanted JSON-document, or use Elastic-file-beat for uploading to Elastic-Server (instead of using Excel).

Comment: That being said, the format you are actually getting is the well-known format [Newline-delimited JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Newline-delimited_JSON) aka [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/).  You can parse it with Json.NET as shown in [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063).

Comment: There's nothing to fix in this question. There's no way to save log entries as an array without deserializing the entire file, modifying the array then writing out again. That's why people use unindented JSON fragments per line in logs or streaming systems for at least 15 years

Comment: There's no way to *read* a log if it's indented JSON either, without reading the entire document and match the opening and closing brackets or braces. Checking the last 5 log entries would be as expensive as reading all of them. With unindented newline delimited JSON though, all a reader has to do is skip to the next newline and start reading the records.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<layout ...indentJson="true">` for prettier json.

Comment: see **Update-1**.

Comment: `indentJson="true"` will help to make JSON-output human readable, but it will cause NLog not to write newline-delimited-JSON (NDJSON). It becomes harder/impossible for LogReaders to parse the JSON-output when adding extra newlines to prettify.