# Converting string with list of Jarray Objects to JSONin C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string like

```
string str = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],
```

I converted it to Jarray with the below code,

```
JArray obj=JArray.Parse(str);
```

Its working fine, but my input string got changed to

```
str=[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],[{"e":"f"},{"g":"h"}]
```

Now the JArray parsing is throwing me an error as its a list of JArray, How can i parse the above string in C#?

Comment: Throws what? What is the *actual* code, actual string? `string str = [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],` is neither valid C# nor valid JSON and definitely not a JSON array

Comment: If the string contained a valid array JSON.NET would parse it without problem.

Comment: Your last string is not a valid JSON string, you can validate it in https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: OK, that's NOT valid JSON. You *can't* have multiple root elements in a JSON string :  `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],      [{"e":"f"},{"g":"h"}]`. That's two separate JSON fragments. An array or arrays would surround this with square brackets, ie `[   [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],      [{"e":"f"},{"g":"h"}]  ]`

Comment: `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],[{"e":"f"},{"g":"h"}]` is not valid json

Comment: Post the *actual* code and strings. Where does this string come from? The code that generates it will have to be fixed, or the string will have to be converted to valid JSON

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16765877/3744182).  Either fix your JSON to have outer brackets as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765884/3744182), or use `new JArray(JsonExtensions.DeserializeDelimitedJson<JArray>(new StringReader(str)).SelectMany(a => a))` where `JsonExtensions.DeserializeDelimitedJson` is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014780/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to parse the following string using [JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm):

> [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],[{"e":"f"},{"g":"h"}]

Thanks @dbc for pointing me in the right direction (see [Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014780/558486)).
 **Please note that this functionality is available only from Release 11.0.1 of Json.NET**.

The following method uses a `JsonTextReader` and returns a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`:

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ParseKeyValuePairs(string json)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(json))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) { SupportMultipleContent = true })
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();

        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var dictionaries = serializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(jsonReader);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue in dictionaries.SelectMany(x => x))
            {
                yield return keyValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the code to generate a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
string json = @"[{""a"":""b""},{""c"":""d""}],[{""e"":""f""},{""g"":""h""}]";

Dictionary<string, string> data = ParseKeyValuePairs(json).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Result:

[image: Dictionary]